# ListView onclick effecting multiple rows

Tags: android, listview

My OnClickListener that I set on my buttons is affecting multiple rows in my ListView. I want one listener per view and one reaction per click.

**GetView**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ConditionChecklist conditionChecklist;
    View view = convertView;

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case 0:
            conditionChecklist = mConditionCheckListArray.get(position);
            view = createDropdownRow(conditionChecklist, convertView, parent);
            break;
        case 1:
            conditionChecklist = mConditionCheckListArray.get(position);
            view = createButtonRow(conditionChecklist, convertView, parent);
            break;
    }

    return view;
}
```

**createButtonRow**

```
public View createButtonRow(ConditionChecklist conditionChecklist, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ButtonHolder buttonHolder;

    if (convertView != null) {
        buttonHolder = (ButtonHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.condition_button_row, parent, false);
        buttonHolder = new ButtonHolder();
        buttonHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_title);
        buttonHolder.yes = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_yes);
        buttonHolder.no = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_no);
        buttonHolder.subQuestion = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_autocomplete);
        convertView.setTag(buttonHolder);
    }

    buttonHolder.title.setText(conditionChecklist.getQuestion());
    setButtonRowListeners(buttonHolder);
    setButtonRowAdapters(buttonHolder);

    return convertView;
}
```

**setButtonRowListeners**

```
private void setButtonRowListeners(final ButtonHolder buttonHolder) {
    buttonHolder.yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonHolder.yes.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            buttonHolder.yes.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            buttonHolder.no.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighterGray));
            buttonHolder.no.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.mediumGray));
            buttonHolder.subQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    buttonHolder.no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonHolder.no.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            buttonHolder.no.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            buttonHolder.yes.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighterGray));
            buttonHolder.yes.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.mediumGray));
            buttonHolder.subQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click any yes or no button it is affecting buttons in rows off the screen so that when I scroll down they are already highlighted. Am I breaking the view holder pattern somewhere? Are my listeners not on a 1-1 relationship like I think they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `OnClickListener` that is the problem.

You are using the ViewHolder pattern, this causes the `ListView` to re-use old views (that are not visible anymore). 
So if you change the properties (backgroundcolor and textcolor) these properties will stay the same when they are re-used.

To fix this; keep track of the clicked items and reset the properties at the beginning of your `getView`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try, please post a small example if you have time.